# Error when connecting to database using unixODBC on IBM AIX

Tags: db2, unixodbc

I am facing an error while connecting to database using unixODBC on IBM AIX 64bit

DB2 client V9.7 is installed on the machine.

Found on net that it can be due to library file:' libdb2o.so ' missing and in that case update to DB2 V9.7 Fix Pack3.

Updated DB2 client to DB2 V9.7 Fix Pack 4 but still no success.

On trying to connect to database using: isql -v  it gives following error: 
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/IBM/db2/V9.7_01/lib64/db2o.o' : file not found 
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

```
Details of .odbc.ini : 
[db2_odbc_source]
Description     = IBM DB2 ODBC data source
Driver          = db2_odbc_driver
Trace           = Yes
DMEnvAttr       = SQL_ATTR_UNIXODBC_ENVATTR={DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH=/home/UserName}

Details of .odbcinst.ini : 
[db2_odbc_driver] 
Description = IBM DB2 ODBC driver 
Driver      = /opt/IBM/db2/V9.7_01/lib64/db2o.o 
FileUsage   = 1  
DontDlClose = 1
```

Environment variables DBINSTANCE and ODBCINI are set.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you should config .odbcinst.ini as:  Driver      = /opt/IBM/db2/V9.7_01/lib64/libdb2o.so

Answer (score 0):

libdb2o.o is used for connectivity via unixodbc for db2 database on 64 bit OS except nt64.on nt64,we use probably db2clio.o